# Dimension of subrepresentations of finite group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I’m very new to representation theory, here is a statement I saw in the course notes from my instructor, he says, for finite group $G$ with a given representation over a complex vector space $V$, any non-trivial subrepresentations can only be at most $|G|$ dimensional. I don’t get the point, all I can figure out is that the statement is true for irreducible representations, any hints on how to understand this statement?

EDIT: I checked with my instructor, and he changed the words: $V$ has a non-zero $G$-invariant subspace of dimensional at most $|G|$. Okay, frankly speaking, I don't see what has changed, any hints? I guess I have a very deep misunderstanding here, please help!

Comment: I think he just meant for irreducible representations.  Consider the trivial group, whose complex representations are just complex vector spaces.  Clearly there are complex vector spaces with subspaces of dimension greater than $1$.

Comment: This is certainly false because $\Bbb C G$ can act on, for example, $\Bbb C G\oplus \Bbb C G$, or $|G|+1$ copies of the trivial representation, etc. The instructor probably meant that either irreducible representations or subrepresentations of the regular representation have dimension $\le |G|$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I agree with you guys, I should check this with my instructor!

Comment: The statement is obviously false.

Comment: What's true is that *cyclic* representations (representations generated by a single vector, including all irreducible representations) are at most $|G|$-dimensional since they're precisely the quotients of the regular representation.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help! I just checked with my instructor and he changed the words, I've made an edition, please check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially @QiaochuYuan's point.  If $V\neq 0$ then pick any non-zero vector $v\in V$.  The $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the vectors $\{gv|g\in G\}$ is a non-zero $G$-invariant subspace of $V$.  As the set of vectors $\{gv|g\in G\}$ has cardinality $|G|$, their span will have dimension at most $|G|$.

Note this is only true under the assumption $V\neq 0$.  That should be in the question somewhere - if not you should mention it to your instructor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although I understand what you mean, but I’m still a little confusing, isn’t a G-invariant subspace a subrepresentation of V? If so, isn’t this equivalent to say every subrepresentation of V has dimension at most |G|? What’s the difference between these two statements, I think this is where I misunderstand deeply.

Comment: The fundamental distinction is between "there exists a ... which is ..." and "every .... is ....".  For example it is true that there exists a prime number which is even.  However it is false to say every prime number is even.  In your case, there exists a non-zero subrepresentation of  $V$ with dimension less than or equal to $|G|$.  However there may also exist non-zero subrepresentations of dimension greater than $|G|$.

Comment: oops, it seems my understanding of English is not very well, I misunderstood the words “has a…”, thank you for your patience clarification!

Comment: Hi, is it correct to say that the span of $\{gv|g\in G\}$, mentioned in your answer, is irreducible for any $G$? If not, is it correct in the case where $G$ is finite?

Comment: @Khal No. For any non-trivial group we have the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G]$, with basis the elements of the group, acted on by group multiplication. Now if we let $v=e$ the identity element in the group, then my construction (the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the vectors $\{gv|g\in G\}$) is the whole of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. However this is not irreducible. For example it properly contains the non-trivial subrepresentation of linear combinations of the group elements, whose coefficients add to $0$. The only group $G$ for which your statement is true is the trivial group.